# Converting a matrix to a square matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

In `MATLAB`, say that we have a matrix with the following dimensions:

```
[11036,1]
```

How can we convert that to a square matrix?

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on whether you want to work by rows or by columns. Assume you have

```
>> m = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
```

and you want to turn it into a 2 x 3 matrix. You can do

```
>> reshape(m,2,3)
ans =
     1     3     5
     2     4     6
```

or

```
>> reshape(m.',3,2).' %// note inversion of size and two transposes
>> ans =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
```

In your case, 11036 is not a perfect square, so you can't convert to a square matrix unless you remove entries from the original matrix or introduce new values in the destination matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [reshape](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) to change a matrix dimensions to the ones you want (as long they're compatible).

Answer (score 1):

Another option. If you want to obtain the smallest square matrix that will hold your vector, and pad any unused elements with zeros, you can use the following:

```
a = rand(11036,1);        % Demo data
n = ceil(sqrt(numel(a))); % Dimension of smallest square matrix
b = zeros(n);
b(1:numel(a)) = a(:);
```

which will create a 106-by-106 matrix in this case. Another simpler example

```
a = 1:13;
n = ceil(sqrt(numel(a))); % 4
b = zeros(n);
b(1:numel(a)) = a(:)
```

returns

```
b =

 1     5     9    13
 2     6    10     0
 3     7    11     0
 4     8    12     0
```